# How Akeno has both devil wings?

Tags: high-school-dxd

In Highschool DxD new Episode 10, Akeno showed her wings to Issei and told that she have both Devil and Fallen Angel wings. But when I was watching Highschool DxD Born then in Episode 1 during one fight it showed that she has both Devil wings.

So is it possible that it is some kind of mistake or there is any explanation behind this event ? I am not sure but there are few other events too which shows that she has both devil wings in previous episodes too. But how it is possible ?

[image]

Comment: Quite possibly animation error.

Answer (score 2):

### Spoiler alert

Quoting Volume 4 of the light novel,

> different from the usual two wings of devils, one wing was of a devil and the other one was the black wing of a fallen angel.

This is the basis for the scene you saw in High School DxD New.

Now, the background story of Akeno is that she originally possess only fallen angel wings. She was born of a Miko and a fallen angel. However, due to persecution from her mother's family, she ran away and then met Rias, who turned her into a devil, causing her to own both devil wings and fallen angel wings.

The cover of the novel shows her with demon wings. DxD BorN also shows her with devil wings.

So, a logical conclusion that we can draw is that

1. Akeno has both a pair of devil wings.
2. She can make a pair of both. For example left wing is that of a devil and right is that of a fallen angel or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

There is no mistake.
She has both Wings of Devil & Fallen Angel. She just hate it as she thinks her mother died because of his father who is fallen angel.

She afraid of reveling that she is half angel & half devil that's why she normally show devil wings. ( That's what i think.) & She afraid if anyone(issie) know about it, He will hate her but "He tells her that he never disliked the gentle side of her and knowing her past does not change his feelings."

Source http://highschooldxd.wikia.com/wiki/Akeno_Himejima